# 8 GB sd card with ubuntu 14.04 installed showing as 4 GB only

Tags: 14.04, sector-size

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a 8gb SD card, in Windows I check the card with a partition manager and it shows there is one partition with size 8 GB, used 2.5 GB and free 5.3 GB.

Now when I boot ubuntu from the SD card and open file manager, it shows size is 4 GB and free 1.1 GB, and when I open disk manager is shows size is 7.9 GB and free space is 1.3 GB

Why is this happening? and how can I utilize the full space in my SD card?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to GParted to recover lost partition [This will help you](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual)

Comment: Good Know my Friend..